# My JS files are taking corrected path but not working and getting errors like SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, mime-types

I am working on yii2 application.

I want to use js and css files of common in my backend. The paths are common/web/js and common/web/css folders respectively.

I have register js and css through

```
AppAsset::register($this); CommonAppAsset::register($this);
```

But i get errors which is seen in screenshot attched.

[image]

I have check the page source and i am getting js files from backend as well as common folder.

My backend's js file are working and opening from the page source but when i open common folder's js file it is opening frontend(site/index) link. and common folder's js is not working on my code.

My view page name spaces :

```
use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use common\assets\CommonAppAsset;
use backend\widgets\Alert;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */
AppAsset::register($this);
CommonAppAsset::register($this);
```

My CommonAppAsset.php is located at common/assets/CommonAppAsset.php and code of this file as follows:

```
<?php

/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace common\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

//use Yii;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class CommonAppAsset extends AssetBundle {

    //public $basePath = '/yii2_advanced/common/web';
    //public $baseUrl = '/yii2_advanced/common/web';
    public $basePath;
    public $baseUrl;
    public $css = [
        'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all',
        'plugins/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css',
        'css/plugins.css',
        'css/style.css',
        'css/error.css',
        'css/colorbox.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
       'plugins/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js',
        'js/jquery.validate.min.js',
        'js/common.js',
        'js/jquery.colorbox.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        //'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public function init() {
        $this->basePath = '@common_base';
        $this->baseUrl = '@common_base/web';
        //$this->basePath = '@app/common/';
        //$this->baseUrl = '@app/common/web'; 
    }

    /* public $jsOptions = array(
      'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_READY
      ); */
}
```

i have set aliases at common\config\main.php as :

```
Yii::setAlias('@common_base', '/chiefs_rs/common/');
```

I don't know where i am getting wrong. Please help some one.

Comment: can we see the JS - seems to be an issue there

Comment: what you mean by hte JS?

Comment: @treyBake - Yeah, I deleted the comment a couple of minutes ago. It's weird that the response is being delivered to the JavaScript engine, since it seems like it's probably an error response with an HTML error page.

Comment: the js* - as in, can we see the code relating to the error?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha no worries

Comment: @treyBake - That said, the errors are on jQuery plugins.

Comment: i have copied all the JS from another project and it's working over there

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point.. though it seems to be on near-enough every plugin included? In fact it does show every `public $js` script as erroring .. how does yii add them in?

Comment: How can i debug this? :(

Comment: @phpguy - I'd look at the network tab in the web console and see what the responses are for those files. It's almost like they're coming back as HTML error pages but with a 200 status code.

Comment: yes exactly they are pointing to html pages.

Comment: why have you commented out the `yii\web\JqueryAsset` from the depends array?

Comment: I have copied from my another yii project and i suppose to define same structure of previous project but in fresh yii2 advanced.

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was htaccess problem. The js url was redirected to the frontend index page. I remove the htaccess and problem fixed. Thank you so much all of you for taking a look of my problem. Your efforts are appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue. It was htaccess problem. The js url was redirected to the frontend index page. I remove the htaccess and problem fixed. Thank you so much all of you for taking a look of my problem. Your efforts are appreciated. :)

Comment: dude you removed the htaccess from which directory

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam root directory's htaccess.